# Python - Subset data between two datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, subset

I'm trying to subset a dataset to include rows between two dates. However, when I this function:

```
data_norm[(data_norm['publication_date'] > '2016-09-01') & (data_norm['publication_date'] <= '2016-09-30')]
```

I get this:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [categories, company, contents, id, levels, locations, model_type, name, publication_date, refs, short_name, tags, type]
Index: []
```

My guess is that the dates in my subset function differs from the data. This is the data:

```
0   2017-01-30 21:28:12.102749
1   2017-01-30 21:24:32.670365
2   2016-12-29 18:56:37.000000
3   2017-01-13 12:10:55.000000
4   2017-01-30 21:28:33.180670
Name: publication_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Any idea(s)?

Answer (score 3):

This seems like it would be better as a comment, but I don't have the rep for one of those. From the example data you have given, an empty dataframe is the correct result. None of the dates provided fall within your search. If you were to change your end date to 2017-01-01...

```
data_norm[(data_norm['publication_date'] > '2016-09-01') &
          (data_norm['publication_date'] <= '2017-01-01')]
```

It should return

```
2016-12-29 18:56:37.000000
Name: publication_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: The data I provided was only the first 5 rows

Comment: Are you sure that the date range you provided is nonempty in your data set? The condition you set works for me.

Comment: I should have been more clear in my post. I changed the end date in his post from 2016-09-30 to 2017-01-01 to show that it would return something.

Comment: rtk22 is right. I double-checked on my end and got the same results. I posted another answer I came across.

Answer (score 2):

**The effective way to use is**

- `df` is a dataframe name
- `date_column` is a column name which has dtypes  as Date.
- subsetting between two dates
- Use `iloc` or `loc` for Error free code

```
df = df.loc[(df['date_column'] > '2012-08-25') & (df['date_column'] <= '2014-06-24')]
df = df.loc[(df['date_column'] > '2014-06-25') & (df['date_column'] <= '2014-09-25')]
```

Do not use `ix` as it is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

The below code also works:

```
data_norm.ix[(data_norm.publication_date >= '2016-09-01') & (data_norm.publication_data <= '2017-01-01'), : ]
```